# Mongoose findOneandUpdate() $push dynamic update key problem

Tags: mongoose, push, findoneandupdate

```
let countryId = 6263135fd3456f312f76e8cb
let cityKey = 'country.'+(0);

await CountryModel.findOneAndUpdate(
{ _id: countryId}, 
{ $push: {cityKey:[]}},
{new:true});
```

To understand , country Id is the key of this multidimensional array.
the array looks like this in mongo db.

```
_id = Object('6263135fd3456f312f76e8cb')
country:Array
    0:Array
```

just wondering why i cant use the city key to make the push look like this

```
{'country.0':[]}
```

i mean its working when i typed the string like that, but as you would imagine it will be
constantly just add to country.0 path. what i want is ive be able to use a variable and make the key/path ('country.Number') like that.

i try appending the 0 'country'+0 like this but it gives me error

thanks hope you can help me